# Travis-cli build errors but local tests/build is OK

Tags: webpack, vue.js, travis-ci

I cannot get my unit test Ok with Travis.. I don't have any errors ( unit/e2e) running test locally ...

here is the log file [Travis build log](https://travis-ci.org/erwin16/Pomodoro/jobs/287460436)

Got a lot of of component module build errors :

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

and some

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'underscore' 
in :
ERROR in ./src/plugins/VueNoiseGeneratorPlugin.js
ERROR in ./src/vuex/mutations.js
```

and also

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel-runtime/helpers/defineProperty' 
in :
ERROR in ./src/vuex/mutations.js
```

I  am running node v8.4.0 , web pack

what could be wrong ?   feedback welcome !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running version `8.4.0` locally, but Travis runs `4.8.0`, because that's what you've configured in your [`.travis.yml`](https://github.com/erwin16/Pomodoro/blob/f5c49230c52df7f2980d8ee84a331374cec359f4/.travis.yml#L4-L5). The unexpected `{` is likely some [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), which was [first supported in Node version 6](http://node.green/#ES2015-syntax-destructuring--declarations). From the logs I presume that some code in a webpack loader is using it, which means that they do not intend to keep supporting older versions of Node.

You should use a newer version of Node for Travis as well, especially since version 4 is no longer actively maintained, which means that only *critical* fixes are applied, until it reaches the end of life (for details see [Release schedule](https://github.com/nodejs/Release#release-schedule1)). Travis should represent the environments you're targeting / plan to run it on.

Regarding the module not found errors, you're using `underscore` (e.g. in [`VueNoiseGeneratorPlugin.js`](https://github.com/erwin16/Pomodoro/blob/f5c49230c52df7f2980d8ee84a331374cec359f4/src/plugins/VueNoiseGeneratorPlugin.js#L1)), but it's not in your [`package.json`](https://github.com/erwin16/Pomodoro/blob/f5c49230c52df7f2980d8ee84a331374cec359f4/package.json). That means it never gets installed and the only reason that it works locally is that you have installed it without saving it (before npm 5 `--save` is required to actually add it to the `package.json`) or you have installed it outside the project, which is still picked up by Node (for instance globally installed). You have to add it to the `package.json`.

```
npm install --save underscore
```

And lastly, you're using [`babel-plugin-transform-runtime`](https://github.com/erwin16/Pomodoro/blob/f5c49230c52df7f2980d8ee84a331374cec359f4/.babelrc#L11), which [requires `babel-runtime` to be installed](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-transform-runtime#installation) as a dependency. Based on the environment you're targeting, you don't need `babel-plugin-transform-runtime`, so you could remove it entirely. If you still want to use it, you need to install `babel-runtime`.

```
npm install --save babel-runtime
```

Comment: thanks a lot ... my fault ( I am running node 8.4.0 .. typing mistake ) ... got it for the dependencies ( I run an rpm prune  to clear off my local noe_modules and added the requested packages...

Answer (score 0):

I just dealt with this issue for 2 hours :( My problem was that the github repo file names had a different case (lower or uppercase) than my local files. Once I matched my local files to what was on github the errors went away.